# Mixing razor syntax with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my *homecontroller's* index view page, I want to display data extracted from database on a Google map. So, what I do is include the *model.cs* file in *homecontroller.cs* file and pass the entire database data to view by converting it to list and passing as a *Viewbag* object. But now when I try to display *markers on the map* based on database's data, it doesn't show. Even a simple javascript *alert()*  statement doesn't show anything on screen. Following is the code:-

-----------------EventsRegister.cs(Model page)------------

```
namespace CampusConnect.Models
{
    public class EventReg
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EventReg> Events { get; set; }
    }
}
```

-----------------Homecontroller.cs-----------------------

```
namespace CampusConnect.Controllers
{


    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        private EventDBContext db = new EventDBContext();
        private List<EventReg> list;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            list = db.Events.ToList();
            ViewBag.Message = "Please Register/Login to continue";
            ViewBag.EntireList= list;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

----------------Index.cshtml(Homecontroller's index view)----------------

```
@section bodyOrMap {
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
        <div class="content-wrapper">

            @*Google Maps included*@

            <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7TFDjCbI4A10H2J-f6zBFHToFQIs6Z2M&sensor=true"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    function InitializeMap() {
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.8644, 77.8964);
                        var myOptions = {
                            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                            zoom: 17,
                            center: latlng,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.EntireList)
                        {
                        <text>
                        alert(@item.Description);  -------->THIS DOESN'T PRINT
                        </text>
                         }


                        var aListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function (event) {
                            alert("Double click displays values" + event.latLng.lat() + " " + event.latLng.lng());

                        });
                    } //Initialise map function ends
                    window.onload = InitializeMap;

                </script>

                <div id="map" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; /*width: 500px;*/ height: 338px; position: relative; float: left; display: inline; width:49%">

                </div>

            </asp:Content>

        </div>
    </text>
}
else
{
    //some HTML
}
}
```

The map gets displayed but the alert statement doesn't print. Also, the **double click** event handler doesn't work(Although, it worked before when no data was there in the database). I have checked the database and there is a table Events.mdf with a row of data that I entered.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is? I am a newbie at programming in asp.net so it might be a minor point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that `item.Description` doesn't actually store a valid JavaScript string, or if it does, that it's not properly encoded. For example if `item.Discription` had the value `"Hello World!"` then the rendered output of this

```
alert(@item.Description);
```

would be this:

```
alert(Hello World!);
```

which is obviously not valid javascript.

Try something like this instead:

```
alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Description)));
```

Also, you don't need to put `<text>` around the alert (which is also not valid JavaScript) if you print it like this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.EntireList)
{
    @:alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Description)));
}
```

Although, it seems like that `<text>` was probably just some placeholder text for something else.

Comment: @p.s.w.g...yeah that worked...but still when I do @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Latitude)), and pass it as a latitude to place a marker...marker doesn't get placed...any idea why?

Comment: @avinash Hmm, I'm not sure, but look at the generated JavaScript and ensure that the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Razor to output a string, which in the context of the final JavaScript becomes a literal string.  JavaScript requires quotes around literal strings.

Try this:

```
alert("@item.Description");
```

For example, if item.Description contains the value *San Francisco* then your final JavaScript output ends up being:

```
alert("San Francisco");
```

Without the quotes you will have:

```
alert(San Francisco);
```

which will have JavaScript trying to figure out what *San* and *Francisco* mean as JavaScript identifiers.

Comment: This will break if `item.Description` has any `"` or characters.

Comment: Yeah that is true.  I was being a little simplistic.  But the only point I was trying to illustrate was that the Razor output needs to be treated as literal text and it needs to be quoted so that JavaScript sees it as a literal string.